# Can't get my basic Webscraper to launch Google

Tags: python, scrape

I'm trying to test a basic webscraper script and would like to experiment with terminal. When I run the script, no searches are performed. Any idea why?

````
# lucky2.py - Opens several Google search results.

import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

ask = input('What do you want to google?')
print('Googling...') #Display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + str(ask) .join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

#TODO: Retrieve top search result links.

#TODO: Open a browser tab for each result.

# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

# Open a browser tab for each result
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))

```Thanks!!
````

Comment: are you sure res.text include elements that will match your selector?

Comment: Save data to a file and examine it closely in a browser. There are no elements with class 'r' but some urls could be extracted as text by xpath like /html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/a/div[2].